# How to fade in / Animation bottom border from the left to right in navigation list on Hover time?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give a left to right bottom Fade In effect in navigation menu on hover time. Here I am using Bootstrap 4. I have tried below code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="#">Home      </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="#">About Us  </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="#">Portfolio </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

I added a simple css for border

```
.navbar a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    color: black;
}
```

Now my navigation look like below image.

[image]

Now I need help or hints to give left to right fade-in / Animation effect in border on hover time.

Comment: this may be help you: https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/eNNdme

Comment: Thank you @Manish Patel I have solved it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add class line to <a class="line"></a> as below
<html>
<li class="nav-item"><a class='line nav-link' href="#">Home      </a></li>
</html>
<style>
.line {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.line:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #000;
  height: 4px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.line:hover:after,
.line:focus:after,
.line:active:after {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```